# React: is there a different between using curly brackets and omitting them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With curly brackets:

```
<div theBestProp={"diagonal-texture"}> ...
```

vs without curly brackets:

```
<div theBestProp="diagonal-texture"> ...
```

Same question is relevant for the "ref" prop:

With curly brackets (from React's docs), accessible through **this._input**:

```
<div ref={(c) => this._input = c} ...
```

vs without curly brackets, accessible through **this.refs.commander**:

```
<div ref="commander"> ...
```

I've also noticed that everything comes out as strings. For this:

```
<PriceOption id="1" yes="true" price="free" audience="for individuals" plan="Starter" />
```

The props will be this (all strings):

```
{
        "id": "1",
        "yes": "true",
        "price": "free", 
        "audience": "for individuals", 
        "plan": "Starter"
    }
```

So I guess only way to pass booleans and numbers is the following:

```
 <PriceOption id={1} yes={true} price="free" audience="for individuals" plan="Starter" />
```

right?

Comment: well, yes..  it might help to think that PriceOption = {id: 1, price: "free"}, that it is PriceOption is an object with property. (it's called props for a reason)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without the curly it will be a string of diagonal-texture.
With curly. React will try to evaluate it and find a string..
The end result is the same. Just that you take longer steps by telling react to evaluate it.

while the second example:

```
<div ref={(c) => this._input = c} 
// react will run the function inside ref, 
// the arrow function always return something, that's js not react
// this is javascript ES6, not react,  

// the function above is the same as: 
<div ref= { (c) => {                   // arrow function returns a closure
                return this._input = c // the closure is returning this._input
             }) 
}
```

so yeah, in react, `<div ref={} />` this will tell react to evaluate whatever inside the curly.

Comment: Can you please expand on what the best practices or conventions are for using curly brackets vs omitting them in cases where they evaluate to the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

In React JSX syntax, inside of curly braces, Javascript will be evaluated. As the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#attribute-expressions says,

> To use a JavaScript expression as an attribute value, wrap the expression in a pair of curly braces ({}) instead of quotes ("").

In your first example, the expression `"diagonal-texture"` evaluates to the same thing as the string `"diagonal-texture"`. Not so for the expression in the second example.