# What is the difference of className={'container'} with className='container'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was learning React and and wanted to pass className props to a component and would like to know the difference between className={'container'} and className='container' and which one is correct to be used.

Comment: Both of them are correct. First one you would use generally when you want to dynamically resolve the classname

Comment: 1. for multiple class, and 2nd for one class. Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/q/34521797/2845389

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: is there a different between using curly brackets and omitting them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39475986/react-is-there-a-different-between-using-curly-brackets-and-omitting-them)

Answer (score 1):

With your example *`className={'container'}` and `className='container'`*  both does the same there is no difference.

***classname={something}***

where something will be a variable containing class name. Is used for dynamic or condition based assignment of class.

example:

```
classname={(ifsomething)?'red':'blue'}
```

***className='something'***

This is a normal direct assignment of class with its name.

example:

```
classname='red'
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case both are same, but below is the logic when to use what :

So you would like to use `className={'container'}` when suppose there is a condition and you are setting the name of class to a variable. Like `classValue = isError?'error':'noterror'` and then `className = {classValue}`

Now you want to use `className='container'` when you directly want to assign a className.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts